# How to format MarkLogic results when exported to a CSV file

Tags: csv, formatting, xquery, extract, marklogic

I have XML which is structured similar to the example below and I've written an XQuery in MarkLogic to export this to a CSV (see below the XML).

What I need help with is formatting the output so that when I open the CSV file, instead of having all of the output across 1 I'd like it to be grouped "columns" so to speak.

Let's say for the sample below, I'd like to output all of the DataTime and Source element values and have the values in their own columns like this:

```
2012-02-15T00:58:26 a
2012-02-15T00:58:26 b
2012-02-15T00:58:26 c
```

How would I go about that?

Would welcome any reference points or help. Thank you in advance.

Here's the sample XML:

```
<Document xmlns="http://fakeexample.org/schemas">
    <Information>
        <ItemId>1f28cb0c2c4f4eb7b13c4abf998e391e</ItemId>
        <MediaType>Text</MediaType>
        <DocDateTime>2012-02-15T00:58:26</DocDateTime>
    </Information>
    <FilingData>
        <DateTime>2012-02-15T00:58:26</DateTime>
        <Source>a</Source>
        </FilingData>
    <FilingData>
        <DateTime>2012-02-15T00:58:27</DateTime>
        <Source>b</Source>
    </FilingData>
    <FilingData>
        <DateTime>2012-02-15T00:58:28</DateTime>
        <Source>c</Source>
    </FilingData>
</Document>
```

Here's the sample XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";
declare namespace xdmp="http://marklogic.com/xdmp";
declare namespace exam="http://fakeexample.org/schemas";

declare function local:getDocument($url)
{

let $response := xdmp:document-get($url, 
       <options xmlns="xdmp:document-get">
           <repair>full</repair>
           <format>xml</format>
       </options>)

return $response
};

xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/csv"),
xdmp:add-response-header(
      "Content-disposition",
      fn:concat("attachment;filename=", "output", fn:current-time(), ".csv")
    ),
(
let $q := cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("exam:ItemId"), ("1f28cb0c2c4f4eb7b13c4abf998e391e"))

let $results := cts:search(fn:doc(), $q)

for $result in $results
return  fn:string-join((xs:string($result//exam:DateTime),
                        xs:string($result//exam:Source)                     
                        ), "," )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your for loop with this:

```
return

string-join(
    for $result in $results//FilingData
    return  fn:string-join((xs:string($result//exam:DateTime),
                    xs:string($result//exam:Source)                     
                    ), "," )
, "&#10;")
```

That should about do the trick..

Edit: note that I added `//FilingData` behind `$results`. That makes sure DateTime and Source of each FilingData is joined separately, and returned as separate strings of the for loop. That allows the outer string-join to add the required line ends between them.

Note: `&#10;` should be translated to OS specific line endings automatically.

Comment: Don't you need to worry about escaping strings, newlines, and quotes from the content?  (Fwiw, I'd like to see the escaping librari-tized so it could be re-used :)

Comment: @eric-bloch With the given XML, no. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that still wrote out the results across 1 row like: date1,date2,date3,source1,source2,source3. Looking at figuring out how to use maps now. Will post an update if I get it to work.

Comment: @zrdunlap Ah, that cts:search returns entire documents, while you want each FilingData on a separate row. You need to select those. You could either fiddle with the cts:search, but perhaps just easier to add a path to them in the for loop. I'll edit my solution.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @grtjn:

```
string-join(..., "&#10;")
```

Line endings can be treated differently depending on OS or application. You could try alternative characters (either or both):

```
"&#x0A;" (LF) 
"&#x0D;" (CR)
```

Also, this could be thwarted by the application used to view the CSV. For example, most versions of Microsoft Excel will convert all whitespace within a cell - newlines included - into plain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, tried both of these as well and am still getting: 2012-02-15T00:58:26,2012-02-15T00:58:26,2012-02-15T00:58:27,2012-02-15T00:58:28,a,b,c  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but still haven't figured out what yet.